# Why does Windows 11 change the UEFI boot order?

Tags: windows, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I am dual booting a Dell Precision 7520 with Fedora 35 and Windows. Worked fine with Windows 10. "Up"graded to Windows 11 and now every time I boot into W11 it puts its own boot loader ahead of "fedora" in UEFI Setup. So every time after booting into W11, I need to hit F2 and reset the boot order in the UEFI Setup.

I've developed a workaround, but it doesn't survive an update to W11's bootmgfw.efi file, nor an update to grub.cfg. Nevertheless, my solution means that I can go for many months without having to do it again. Here is my workaround:

1. boot into Linux
2. Make a backup of the MS Boot directory, just in case:

```
cd /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft
cp -a Boot Boot.bak
```

3. Then do the following,

```
cd /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot
cp -p bootmgfw.efi bootmgf2.efi
cp -p /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grubx64.efi bootmgfw.efi
cd /boot/efi/EFI/fedora
cp -p grub.cfg grub.cfg.bak
```

4. Now edit grub.cfg and replace "bootmgfw" with "bootmgf2" (note that the real grub.cfg might be in /boot/grub2 rather than in /boot/efi/EFI/fedora)
5. reboot

Now when Windows 11 puts itself top of the list in the boot order, and boots its bootmgfw.efi, it is actually booting grubx64.efi, which loads grub.cfg. As mentioned, you'll have to repeat steps 3 and 4 when bootmgfw.efi and/or grub.cfg are updated. I turned the above into a script which I only have to run once every several months when W11 updates its bootmgfw.efi file.

Given the non-permanent nature of the above solution, is there a better solution? Note that after weeks of researching this problem, I came across a solution suggested by "Piotr" a few years ago to reset Windows "{bootmgr}" to \EFI\fedora\grubx64.efi, but that didn't work. Windows had no idea about \EFI\fedora...

Comment: Years ago your fix was the first workaround we had for UEFI dual booting. But grub only boots working Windows & if Windows turned fast start up on or needed chkdsk, grub would not boot it and you needed a Windows repair flash drive. And as you found, Windows updates reset everything. Can you boot Ubuntu from f12? And then just use efibootmgr to reset boot order? See `man efibootmgr` & efibootmgr -o command: https://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr & https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win

Comment: Good to hear that this workaround already existed. Apparently it should not have disappeared. Yes, I can reset the boot order from F12 or F2, I just don't want to have to do so after every time I boot into W11. The efibootmgr doesn't block W11 from resetting the boot order. Another solution is to put a password on UEFI Setup, but I'm scared to do that. If I forget the password, I'm really cooked.

Comment: Do not have good answer. But I would boot from f12, and run efibootmgr to change boot order. Some users do not use grub and always boot with f12. Or change to rEFInd which may have same issue? http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/